# Configuring HPA using cross project pub/sub metrics in GCP

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to configure HPA for GKE workload in one of our projects (lets say ProjectA) using the pubsub metrics from another project of ours (lets say ProjectB). I receive the following permission denied error:

```
Warning FailedGetExternalMetric 9s (x12 over 2m56s) horizontal-pod-autoscaler unable to get external metric default/pubsub.googleapis.com|subscription|num_undelivered_messages/&LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string{resource.labels.project_id: ProjectB,resource.labels.subscription_id: ProjectB.Subscription,},MatchExpressions:[]LabelSelectorRequirement{},}: unable to fetch metrics from external metrics API: the server could not find the descriptor for metric pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/num_undelivered_messages: googleapi: Error 403: Permission monitoring.metricDescriptors.get denied (or the resource may not exist)., forbidden
```

I have Mpnitoring.admin role assigned on both the projects and have pub/sub APIs enabled on both the projects.

Also, I am able to configure HPA for GKE workload in ProjectA using the pubsub metrics from with the ProjectA. I want to not extend the same configuration using metrics from ProjectB.

Can anybody assist me on the issue please?

Followed the KB to configure the HPA:

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/autoscaling-metrics?_ga=2.189193512.-2038413145.1679461982#pubsub_7

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a service account for `custom-metrics-adapter` workload in Project A, assign permissions to this IAM service account in Project B, and bind this IAM service account to `custom-metrics` Kubernetes Service account.

The given steps are for the GKE cluster with Workload Identity.

1. Create a IAM service account in Project A.
2. Assign `Monitor Viewer` role to this service account in Project B.
3. Mark IAM service account to be used as Kubernetes workload identity

   gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding --role 
   roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser --member 
   "serviceAccount:.svc.id.goog[custom-metrics/custom-metrics-stackdriver-adapter]" 
   @.iam.gserviceaccount.com
4. Change `custom-metrics-stackdriver-adapter` Kubernetes Service account to use created IAM service account:

   kubectl annotate serviceaccount --namespace custom-metrics 
   custom-metrics-stackdriver-adapter 
   iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account=@.iam.gserviceaccount.com

see details: [Start Custom Metrics - Stackdriver Adapter section](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-stackdriver/tree/master/custom-metrics-stackdriver-adapter#configure-cluster)

Comment: wasted so many hours trying to figure this out on Autopilot. Google Cloud docs are so bad D: